# Using JSON to fill header data but receiving the error "Cannot read property appendChild of undefined"

Tags: javascript, json

So I have a javascript file that should pull the JSON data and frequent the header with a h1 tag using the title from the JSON file, but it doesn't seem to be pulling any of the data at all and I am getting the error message `Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined` in the console log

Here is my javascript file:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 title();
});

var header = document.getElementsByName("header");

function title() {
loadJSON(function(response) {
   var json = JSON.parse(response);
   var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.textContent = json.pageone.page_title;
    header.appendChild(h1);
   });
  }

function loadJSON(callback) {
var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
xobj.open('GET', 'dist/json/data.json', true);
xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == 200) {
    callback(xobj.responseText);
  }
};
xobj.send(null);
```

}

And this is the JSON data I am trying to pull:

```
{
 "pageone":{
 "page_title": "This is a title",
 "page_description": "This is a description"
 },
```

Comment: Where is `loadJSON` from? Can you see the request being made in the devtools?

Comment: I've just updated the code with `loadJSON`

Comment: @chrisg86 I can see the request yeah, and it picks up JSON data, it just doesn't seem to be processing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByName("header");
```

will return a node list so you would need to target

```
document.getElementsByName("header")[0];
```

To target the first (and I'm guessing only if it's header) on the page. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've added this but it still doesn't seem to be pulling the data/frequenting the header

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I'm not sure then, my XMLHTTP knowledge is sketchy at best, I'd just noticed that one thing and thought it could be that. Hope someone else can help. The above does still stand though, you will need to target the specific element, or loop through them if you want to target all.

Comment: Ah no worries, but thank you for your help with targeting the first header!

Comment: Did you mean `getElementsByTagName`?